# how to exclude ftp traffic from being routed trough vpn?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn, ftp, routing, filezilla

I'm using openvpn and the network-manager to connect to ghostvpn and everything's
fine, but I want to exclude all ftp traffic from the vpn connection, because I
need more speed for up/downloads. Up till now I have to disconnect from the vpn server for the time that I'm doing my up and downloads - that's not a cool solution ;)

How can I do that? Or maybe there's an option in filezilla?

Thanks in advance!

Sebastian

Comment: Some clarification. You want to deny `ftp` traffic at all when you are on `vpn` or?

Comment: No, I want the ftp traffic going directly to the internet without using the vpn network.

Comment: Only `ftp`? Where you wish to route `http`?

Comment: its like: if( traffic == ftp) take normal route to internet else: use vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can route `ftp` directly to internet with `iptables`

Here we shall take `ftp` for routing. Use `mangle` table of `iptables` for modifying the `ftp` packets.

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

We are marking all packets with destination port `21` as `0x1` .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
sudo service iptables save
sudo service iptables restart
```

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` by just giving an entry

```
100 ftptable
```

Write rule for `ftp` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 lookup ftptable
```

Add route at new table `ftptable`. All other traffic will go through the
vpn if is vpn set like default gateway, which can be seen by `ip route show` command.

Do this first time when you are connected to vpn.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table ftptable $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `ftp` packets to table `ftptable`

```
sudo ip route add default dev <your_interface> table ftptable
```

`your_interfrace` in command is you usual wifi or eth interface to access internet when you are not connected to internet.

Use `ip route show table ftptable` to show all routes at `ftptable`.

EDIT 1

Second way

Edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add a new table by appending the following line:

```
100 ftptable
```

Configure your new routing table named `ftptable` with a default gateway and create rules to conditionally send traffic to that table.

```
ip route add default via <usual_gw_ip> dev <your_int> table ftptable
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table ftptable
```

Your final annotated script would look like this:

```
# Populate secondary routing table
ip route add default via <usual_gw_ip> dev <your_int> table ftptable
# Anything with this fwmark will use the secondary routing table
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table ftptable
# Mark these packets so that iproute can route it through ftptable
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o <your_int> -p tcp --dport 21 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# now rewrite the src-addr
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o <your_int> -p tcp --dport 21 -j SNAT --to <your_local_ip>
```

Try.

EDIT 2

When you are connected to vpn I guess that all traffic go trough them. In you routing table you will see default gw to `tun0` interface.
Simple add route to route traffic to ftp server to different interface/ip

```
ip route add <your_ftp_server_ip/32> dev <your_exit_int>

<your_exit_int> - represent not tun interface example: eth0, ens160, ...
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try that later! This looks really promising.